# what causes the URL to change upon form submissions

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I often seen websites with a search function and when they search for something, the web page often changes the url to something along the lines of 
search.php?q="searchquery"& etc , i have a search page on my site and i use ajax to submit a form that has a search input and sends to a php page which searches through my database and returns data to a specific div on the original page via echo.

```
function getdata() {
   var str = document.getElementById("searcb");
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You are searching for: " + str.value;
   document.getElementById("searchresults").style.display="block";

 if (str == "") { 
       document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "";
       return;
         }  
else {

      var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("searchresults").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }

    xmlhttp.open("GET", "getuser.php?q=" + str.value, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    return false;
    }
}
```

HTML

```
   <form  onsubmit="return getdata()">
   <input type="search" id="searcb" name="searchBar"></br></br>
   </form>
```

My question is what am i doing differently that causes my url to remain the same compared to a common search engine

Comment: When a url changes eg. `?q="searchquery` it means that it the part behind the `=` sign is used by a `$_GET`. But because you use ajax which is javascript the page doesn't need to be reloaded where the page needs to be reloaded when using `$_GET`

Comment: I think it mean javascript history api. You can use this api to manipulate your url without reloading at all. Demo : [http://html5demos.com/history](http://html5demos.com/history)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general the url change because a post that reload the page is performed. Your url will not change because you call make an ajax call that will not reload your corrent page .